# How can I find the Minimum of months in text format?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a report that gives sales performance by month and product code:

```
ProdID  -  Month  -  Qty

1234    -  April  -  10

1234    -  May    -  5

5678    -  April  -  4

5678    -  May    -  7
```

I want to dynamically drive the column headers when I look this data up into another sheet... so one would be "April", the next "May"... and then next month, when I drop the next report in, I want those headers to change to "May" and "June"

I thought a =min  on the month column might have returned "April", but it returns "00 January 1900"

Is there a way I can return the value "April" from interrogating the Month column?

Comment: that comment looks like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try (with dynamic range):

[image]

Formula in cell `E1`:

```
=INDEX(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),MATCH(SMALL(MONTH(DATEVALUE("1-"&B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))&"-2019")),1),MONTH(DATEVALUE("1-"&B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))&"-2019")),0))
```

> **Note:** Enter as array through
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can also leave out the `MONTH` function:

```
=INDEX(B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),MATCH(SMALL(DATEVALUE("1-"&B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))&"-2019"),1),DATEVALUE("1-"&B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))&"-2019"),0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This does work, but only if I specify exactly the report length, so, I have to put :   =INDEX(D2:D13257,....  and the report length will change day, to day.    If I put an upper limit that will include blank rows, =INDEX(D2:D20000,....   for example, i get  "#Value!".     Do you know if there is a way around this?

Comment: That has solved my issue for column header 1 perfectly,thank you. The next problem is column header 2. As "April" exists multiple times in the list, the 2nd smallest value is also "April", and the 3rd, and the 4th, etc.......   How do I pick out "May"??    I tried a +1, didnt expect it to work and it didnt.

Comment: @EdTattersall, to extract May, you just need to have a +1 at the end of the `MATCH` function. Like so: `....MATCH(SMALL(MONTH(DATEVALUE("1-"&B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))&"-2019"))+1,1)....`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform`) available in Excel 2010+ to create a Pivot table, which can be easily updated when your data changes.

The "key" part for sorting is to add a Custom Column with the formula:

```
Date.Month(Date.FromText("2000" & [Month] & "1"))
```

which converts the Month name into a number.

You then sort on that column, then delete it.

Finally, you Pivot on the month column and create your table.

So, **given**:

[image]

**Results**

[image]

This can be done from the GUI, but the M-code is:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ProdID", Int64.Type}, {"Month", type text}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Date.Month(Date.FromText("2000" & [Month] & "1"))),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Custom"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Month]), "Month", "Qty", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

If needed, you can easily add a `totalProd` column in the PQ, and a `Total` row for the months in the resultant table on the worksheet.